# Buildozer update python code

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

This may sound dumb, but I am unable to figure out how to update my `main.py` code using buildozer. I once created a file `main.py` and ran `buildozer init` . Afterwards I executed some android commands like `buildozer android run`. Now I would like to change the code of my `main.py` . But whenever I try to re-compile using `buildozer android run` the same not edited code is used. I found out that the file `PROJECT/.buildozer/android/app/main.py` is used. But I don't want to update this file because that seems unclean to me.

**Edit**: I already tried `buildozer android clean` and `buildozer android update` and I already searched on the internet but I could not find anything.

What is the solution to update the buildozer codebase?

Answer (score 4):

Well, a very stupid solution. After 45 minutes of trial-and-error I found out that I just have to invoke `buildozer android debug` to **compile** the application. `buildozer android run` is independent and just **runs** the compiled application. As a user of the gradle build system I did not think about this case, because I was familar with the target-based build system.

The final solution to compile and run on the target device is therefore: `buildozer android debug deploy run`

I hope this answer will help someone who expects the same problem.